# Cannot launch Cordova iOS emulator - PhoneGap on Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, emulation

When trying to launch the emulator for iOS I get the following message:

```
peters-mbp-2:hello pz$ cordova emulate ios
Running command: /Users/pz/ss/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
simctl was not found.
Check that you have Xcode 6.x installed:
    xcodebuild --versionCheck that you have Xcode 6.x selected:
    xcode-select --print-path

Error: /Users/pz/ss/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

My version of Xcode is good, version 6.2 as shown below:

```
peters-mbp-2:hello pz$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.2
Build version 6C131e
```

I believe my path is not set however I'm unsure what to set it to, current path is:

```
peters-mbp-2:hello pz$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Again, I believe I just need to run the following command and it will work, does anyone know what I should set the path to?

```
peters-mbp-2:hello pz$ xcode-select -s <some path>
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem after updating from Mavericks to El Capitan then Xcode 6 to Xcode 7.

Just had to open Xcode so it could finish "Installing components".

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling, then launching Xcode after the install fixed my issue - I did not have to explicitly set a path.